# How do I access images depends on notification type

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I stored notificationType in back end json file, And in notifacation controller i have stored same notificationtype with name and images(which images it supposed to show depends on notification type) for to compare.
 Now i would like to acces the images depends on notification type.
i had tried like this but its taking only 0th position images it is taking.

I got to know what my mistake is but i dont know how to do it can anyone help me...
my code is.

controller.js

```
$scope.typeofnotification =[{name:'offer', imges: './resources/remote.png'},
                {name:'discount', imges:'./resources/mic.png'},
                {name:'upgrades', imges:'./resources/play-icon.png'}];


/*var len = $scope.typeofnotification.length*/
$scope.setNotificationImage = function(){

    var notificationImage;

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.typeofnotification.length; i++) 
    {
        if($scope.notificationData[i].notificationType == $scope.typeofnotification[i].name)
        {
           return notificationImage = $scope.typeofnotification[i].imges;

        }
    }

};
```

notificationData[i].notificationType this line from backend

one.HTML

```
<div class="notifications" ng-repeat="item in notificationData">            
<img id="notificationImages" yo-src="setNotificationImage()"/>  
<div id="notificationdata" yo-attr="{html: 'item.desc'}"></div>                 
<div id="notificationdate" yo-attr="{html: 'item.date'}"></div>                 
</div>
```

In the ng-repeat directive notificationdata comes from backend
 output what i am getting is, only 1st image oth position image i am getting for all notification.
but i want images depends on notification type.
as for above code, If notification type is add_content it needs to display remote.png and if type is 'discount' it needs to display mic.png and finaly if typeis upgrades it needs to display play-icon.png

plz check images below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoFGY.png)

Comment: in your PS your notificationType and typeof notifaction have diffenet names?

Comment: no sir both is same but thing is every time function starts from zero thats what its shows same image no every notification.

Answer (score 0):

In your solution you only get same value because of when satisfied first condition return that image url not your item image url.

you need to check with repeated `item` instead of `$scope.notificationData` so need to pass `item` when call `setNotificationImage` function and check with this `item.notificationType === $scope.typeofnotification[i].name`

like:

HTML:

```
<div class="notifications" ng-repeat="item in notificationData">            
    <img id="notificationImages" yo-src="setNotificationImage(item)"/>  //pass item 
    <div id="notificationdata" yo-attr="{html: 'item.desc'}"></div>                 
    <div id="notificationdate" yo-attr="{html: 'item.date'}"></div>                 
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.setNotificationImage = function(item){

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.typeofnotification.length; i++) 
    {
        if(item.notificationType === $scope.typeofnotification[i].name)
        {
           return  $scope.typeofnotification[i].imges;

        }
    }

};
```

Comment: you are welcome and can accept this answer if it helped you :) @chandru